# Highcharts Line Area chart data formatting issue

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts, laravel-5

I am using Laravel backend to generate a raw data array for Highcharts. I am using [this Highcharts example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series) as the basis.I cannot get my chart to format the x axis date nor the tooltip to show the correct date (like the example). I think my problem is in the data format.

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/x5kpLxy0/)

My Laravel controller code:

```
$transactionData = Transaction::where('type', '=', 'INVOICE')
    ->whereNotIn('status', ['DRAFT', 'CANCELLED'])
    ->where('issue_date', '>=', $fiscal_start)
    ->orderBy('due_date', 'asc')
    ->select(['issue_date', 'amount_transaction_total'])
    ->get()->toArray();

$invoicedLineChartData = [];
foreach ($transactionData as $data) {
    $invoicedLineChartData[] = [
        Carbon::parse($data['issue_date']), 
        floatval($data['amount_transaction_total']))
    ];
}
```

This generates data that looks like this:

```
[[{"date":"2016-07-04 01:11:07.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},909],
 [{"date":"2016-07-04 01:11:07.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},1988]...]
```

I can see from the Highcharts example that the AJAX returns data that looks like this:

```
[[Date.UTC(2013,5,2),0.7695],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,3),0.7648],
[Date.UTC(2013,5,4),0.7645],...]
```

What is the correct way to format the data on the back end for this Highchart type from Laravel side? I have tried various Carbon formats but the result is still not correct.

Additionally, why does the y axis start at -500 when there are no negative entries in the data? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using `$data['issue_date']` directly or reformatting it as ISO?

Comment: Hi @RC, yes I have. the only difference seems to be in the tooltip formatting (with Carbon it shows `Thursday January 1,...` with no Carbon `01/01/...`. x Axis remains per the fiddle. Same result with Carbon to ISO (`->toIso8601String()`)

Comment: Playing around a little with your data, I got this:http://jsfiddle.net/ayxhw7n4/1/ as you can see, there is some transformation going on (I take you date object and parse it as a date, then I sort the data by date). So you should be able to figure out something working from my fiddle.

Comment: @RC thanks, I will play around with it.

Comment: I think (Not 100% sure but the way i do it) The dates need to be backwards in time and use (Date.parse(thedate)) to get the miliseconds and then evaluate the whole data ( eval(data);)  -- check my demo - http://jsfiddle.net/d4oy4o3h/ -- as for the time i think its the same thing you will need to convert time to miliseconds

Comment: Opps i dint see RC gave you a heads up :) -- yeah convert the dates to miliseconds

Comment: Check here for another way to it like you have in your Q as long as you have a steady interval time -- http://jsfiddle.net/Fp5GA/